# Parse Android Volley JSONArray response

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm sending a JSONArray GET request with Volley, and it's returning the specified JSON array. Here's my Request:

```
JsonArrayRequest getRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
                    {
                        @Override public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                            Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                        }
                    }
                  );
                  VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(getRequest); //Call to get dashboard feed
}
```

As you can see, I'm currently just logging out the response. I want to parse the Array though and display the results in a list view. The documentation for this isn't great, and I'm pretty green in terms of Android dev. What is the proper way to parse a JSON array from Volley and display the results in a list view? [I've gathered](http://javadocs.okadatech.com/javadoc/volley/reference/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonArrayRequest.html) that I should use `parseNetworkResponse`, but not sure how to implement.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'd recommend to stick to the GSON library for JSON parsing. Here's how a Volley request with embedded JSON processing could look then:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;

/**
 * Volley GET request which parses JSON server response into Java object.
 */
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {

    /** JSON parsing engine */
    protected final Gson gson;

    /** class of type of response */
    protected final Class<T> clazz;

    /** result listener */
    private final Listener<T> listener;

    public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz, Listener<T> listener, 
            ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);

        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.gson = new Gson();
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json = new String(
                    response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(
                    gson.fromJson(json, clazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

Let's imagine you have a server method located at http://example.com/api/persons/ which returns a JSON array of Person; Person is as follows:

```
public class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

We can call the abovementioned method like this:

```
GsonRequest<Person[]> getPersons = 
        new GsonRequest<Person[]>("http://example.com/api/persons/", Person[].class,

            new Listener<Person[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Person[] response) {
                    List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(response);
                    // TODO deal with persons
                }

            }, new ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO deal with error
                }
            });

VolleyQueue.get().add(getPersons);
```

And finally in response listener we get an array of Person which can be converted to list and fed to ListView's adapter.

Comment: Where does the last code snippet go? And where is VolleyQueue defined?

Comment: can we use the type token method here?

Comment: Nice sample.its helped.!

Comment: @Greg  try like this    VolleyHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(getPersons);

Create a volley helper class to add the request queue.

if you need the sample i can provide !.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) project to working with json in java and android app ,it is so simple 
this link is a sample link of using gson

[How To Convert Java Object To / From JSON (Gson)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the native `JSONParsor` in the android framework your requirements are comparatively less and the `JSON` is **simple**. [Here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidhive.info%2F2012%2F01%2Fandroid-json-parsing-tutorial%2F&ei=oGaqU-6LJMiXuATD7oGgCA&usg=AFQjCNFpl6XGR1b0nWBdwIDwnrhaxPGbug&sig2=UKN-LQUC9Qr21MlHmUU-Zg&bvm=bv.69620078,d.c2E) is a link for the tutorial.

But if you are using **complex** `JSON` objects, use libraries like

- **GSON**
- **Jackson**

I find **GSON** easier and more effective to use. You know more about it from [Here](http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON)

Comment: Thank you, I will likely use GSON. Can you elaborate on how to actually parse an Array though? The example you referenced uses AsyncTask, not Volley so it's a bit confusing. I've found there are lots of resources on parsing a JSONObject, but not as many for an Array which is what I'm dealing with.

Comment: pass the response string from `volley` to `gson`