# JSON Spring Framework Android

Tags: java, android, spring, gradle, frameworks

Good evening,

Im learning Android Developing in Android Studio im orginal C# developer
and im now at the point i parse json to my android app

with the following code in my Events.java

```
  public static class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Events> {
    @Override
    protected Events doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            String url = "http://example.com/Example.ashx?Onderdeel=Feeds&AuthToken=" + Core.AuthToken;
            Log.e("Ophalen Events", url);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            Events events = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Events.class);

            // Log.e("EVENTS:", events.getContent());

            return events;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

i call this piece of code in my onCreateView
like

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);

new Events.HttpRequestTask().execute();


 return rootView;
}
```

The problem is i want to return the Object /Class Events

Like Events e = Events.HttpRequestTask().execute();
and than e = my filled object.

Does someone has any tips or ideas since im new to this :)
ty very much

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 3):

Calling execute() will return AsyncTask itself, you need to call get() method on top of it.

```
Events e = new HttpRequestTask().execute().get();
```

Comment: Error:(93, 42) error: cannot find symbol method HttpRequestTask()

Comment: I have updated my answer I copied this line from your question, I thought you have async task "HttpRequestTask" in your Events class

Comment: Error:(94, 78) error: unreported exception InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: You might have some more errors but I am sure you will get your Events object once you call get() method at the end, I will take a look at your code once more

Comment: public static class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Events> {} is inside my Events class –  Stefan van de Laarschot just now   edit

Comment: Can you paste the whole stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Calling execute() will return AsyncTask itself, Pass the reponse to

```
Event getEvent(String response){
Event e=new Event();
// parse the data & set the model data.
return e;
}
```

**For Standard Android way coding request.**
for network request use the **volley** google library. For parsing the JSON use **GSON** library. 
For simple example just go through below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/24433916/3187349
In android fallow the **MVP** architecture go through this tutorial. 
http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/

Answer (score 0):

Already done it with SpringFramework.