# Android volley JSONArrayRequest not getting response

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

my JSONArrayRequest doesn't seem to be getting any response from the url
This is the URL = "http://susuonlinesegar.esy.es/track_pesanan.php?ID=P77997"

```
 private void getCoordinate(){
    URL_KOORDINAT += "?ID=" + idPesanan;
    Log.e("URL", URL_KOORDINAT);
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_KOORDINAT,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.e("Response",response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Comment: post your logcat, look whether there is any error response

Comment: may be help you [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24433916/4824159)

Answer (score -2):

You can get response by following this code

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                "Your url here",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Here from response u can get what u need


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        pDialog.hide();
                        VolleyLog.e("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("", "");
here in params send what parameters need to be send to get response if needed

                return params;
            }
        };
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(sr);
```