# Android Parse Json Response To Java ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am trying to make a GET request to my WCF service via Volley and i want to parse its response to a Java `ArrayList`. Here is my method

```
    public ArrayList<Company> getCompanies(){

        String url = AUDITTRACKINGAPP_SERVICE_URI + "GetCompanies";
        String tagJsonReq = "companiesRequest";

        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        pDialog.show();

        final ArrayList<Company> companies = new ArrayList<Company>();

        JsonObjectRequest companiesRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(  Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES RESPONSE:" + response.toString());

                        try {
                            JSONArray companiesJson = response.getJSONArray("GetCompaniesResult");

                            for (int i = 0; i < companiesJson.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jObject = (JSONObject)companiesJson.get(i);

                                Company company = new Company();
                                company.setCompanyId(Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("CompanyId")));
                                Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyId:" + jObject.getString("CompanyId"));
                                company.setCompanyName(jObject.getString("CompanyName"));
                                Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyName:" + jObject.getString("CompanyName"));

                                companies.add(company);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES RESPONSE ERROR ON PARSING JSON:" + e.getMessage());
                        }

                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES onErrorResponse:" + error.getMessage());
                    pDialog.hide();
                }
            });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(companiesRequest, tagJsonReq);

    return companies;
}
```

> JSON RESPONSE:

```
 {"GetCompaniesResult":[{"CompanyId":1,"CompanyName":"CompanyName1"},{"CompanyId":2,"CompanyName":"CompanyName2"}]}
```

I am able to get JSON response but `ArrayList<Company>` returns null. I think that`onResponse` is a calback method and runs in an another thread so i cant populate the list but since i am a Android newbie i dont know how to manage this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you getting output in log?

Comment: Yes i see the JSON response @AiyazParmar

Comment: is your for loop executing successfully?

Comment: can you show your json response?

Comment: can you paste your JSON here?

Comment: where are you accessing Arraylist<Company> ?

Comment: Will update the question with JSON response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Android Volley JSONArray response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401094/parse-android-volley-jsonarray-response)

Comment: Can you put the entire class code here

Comment: @ankitaggarwal other content of the class is not related to my question

Answer (score 5):

You need to create json object of each element of json array

```
try {
                            JSONArray companiesJson = response.getJSONArray("GetCompaniesResult");

                            for (int i = 0; i < companiesJson.length(); i++) {


                    JSONObject obj = Website.getJSONObject(i);


                                Company company = new Company();
                                company.setCompanyId(Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("CompanyId")));
                                Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyId:" + obj.getString("CompanyId"));
                                company.setCompanyName(obj.getString("CompanyName"));
                                Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyName:" + obj.getString("CompanyName"));

                                companies.add(company);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES RESPONSE ERROR ON PARSING JSON:" + e.getMessage());
                        }
```

Comment: He is already doing this here: JSONObject jObject = (JSONObject)companiesJson.get(i);

Answer (score 0):

`JsonObjectRequest` works **asynchronous** because of that the main thread continue running and a new thread is created to run JsonObjectRequest and the result is that your returns is null. Call a method in your class to send the data back and call it when you finish managing the json data, for example:

```
public void manageCompaniesData(ArrayList<Company>){

    //YOUR CODE HERE.

}
```

Your code modified:

```
public ArrayList<Company> getCompanies(){

String url = AUDITTRACKINGAPP_SERVICE_URI + "GetCompanies";
        String tagJsonReq = "companiesRequest";

        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        pDialog.show();

        final ArrayList<Company> companies = new ArrayList<Company>();

        JsonObjectRequest companiesRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(  Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES RESPONSE:" + response.toString());

                        try {
                            JSONArray companiesJson = response.getJSONArray("GetCompaniesResult");

                            for (int i = 0; i < companiesJson.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jObject = (JSONObject)companiesJson.get(i);

                                Company company = new Company();
                                company.setCompanyId(Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("CompanyId")));
                                Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyId:" + jObject.getString("CompanyId"));
                                company.setCompanyName(jObject.getString("CompanyName"));
                                Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyName:" + jObject.getString("CompanyName"));

                                companies.add(company);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES RESPONSE ERROR ON PARSING JSON:" + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        manageCompaniesData(companies);
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES onErrorResponse:" + error.getMessage());
                    pDialog.hide();
                }
            });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(companiesRequest, tagJsonReq);

    }
```

Comment: That's why he is passing a Response.Listener to the call, in order to manage the async response

Comment: Check where is the return of this function, and when is going to be call onResponse.

Comment: As i mentioned in the question i knew that is the problem but i am not able to implement it so ended up here.

Comment: Now I understand what you need, try with the code which I posted

Comment: The same as you are doing after calling getCompanies(); post the code where you are calling getCompanies() and I can figure out what you should do in manageCompaniesData()

Answer (score 0):

`JSONArray` objects have a function `getJSONObject(int index)` so you have to use

```
JSONObject jObject = companiesJson.getJSONObject(i);
```

instead of

```
JSONObject jObject = (JSONObject)companiesJson.get(i);
```

Try this code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < companiesJson.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject jObject = companiesJson.getJSONObject(i);
  Company company = new Company();
  company.setCompanyId(jObject.getInt("CompanyId")));
  company.setCompanyName(jObject.getString("CompanyName"));
  companies.add(company);
 }
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < companiesJson.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject jObject = (JSONObject)companiesJson.get(i);
  Company company = new Company();
  company.setCompanyId(Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("CompanyId")));
  Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyId:" + jObject.getString("CompanyId"));
  company.setCompanyName(jObject.getString("CompanyName"));
  Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyName:" + jObject.getString("CompanyName"));

  companies.add(company);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse you json like this inside the `for` loop.Also Don't declare `ArrayList` companies as `final`.

```
Company company = new Company();
JSONObject jObject = (JSONObject)companiesJson.optJSONObject(i); 
if(jObject != null){ 
   company.setCompanyId(jObject.optInt("CompanyId")));
   company.setCompanyName(jObject.optString("CompanyName"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You wanna json values for CompanyID and CompanyName try the below snippet.
for (int i = 0; i < companiesJson.length(); i++) {

```
                        JSONObject jObject = companiesJson.getJSONObject(i);
                        Company company = new Company();
                        company.setCompanyId(Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("CompanyId")));
                        Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyId:" + jObject.getString("CompanyId"));
                        company.setCompanyName(jObject.getString("CompanyName"));
                        Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyName:" + jObject.getString("CompanyName"));
                        companies.add(company);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you get any JSON exception in logcat, try this once.

```
for (int i = 0; i < companiesJson.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jObject = companiesJson.getJSONObject(i);
                            Company company = new Company();
                            company.setCompanyId(Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("CompanyId")));
                            Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyId:" + jObject.getString("CompanyId"));
                            company.setCompanyName(jObject.getString("CompanyName"));
                            Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyName:" + jObject.getString("CompanyName"));
                            companies.add(company);
 }
```

Comment: do you get result for  "Log.v(TAG, "COMPANIES setCompanyId:" + jObject.getString("CompanyId"));" in logcat.