# Parsing JSONArray using Gson + Volley not getting response

Tags: java, android, json, gson, android-volley

So I am trying to parse an array of objects from json using Google's Gson library and Volley for HTTP requests. My issue is it's as if **the code isn't 'hitting' the `OnResponse` call**. I've tried adding a simple Log printout within the function just to see if it does anything.

My `GsonRequest` class comes straight from [Google's Training Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html). I constructed these methods based on an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401094/parse-android-volley-jsonarray-response).

This is my code:

```
private void runVolleyJson() throws AuthFailureError {
    GsonRequest<Meetings> getMeetings = new GsonRequest<Meetings>(AUTH_URL, Meetings.class, getHeaders(),
            createMyReqSuccessListener(),
            createMyReqErrorListener());
    helper.add(getMeetings);
}

private Response.Listener<Meetings> createMyReqSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<Meetings>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Meetings response) {
            // NOTHING HAPPENS FROM HERE!
            try {
              Log.d("response", response.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Do whatever you want to do with response;
            // Like response.tags.getListing_count(); etc. etc.
        }
    };
}

private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Do whatever you want to do with error.getMessage();
        }
    };
}

public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Content-Type", "application/json;");
    map.put("Authorization", "Bearer <sometoken>");
    return map;
}
```

There is absolutely no error. It is authorizing the request, but nothing happens in `OnResponse`, it just seems to ignore that function.

Now I've tried using a standard `StringRequest` with volley and it works flawlessly, like this:

```
    private void runVolleyTest() {

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, AUTH_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                                                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            Meeting m = gson.fromJson(jsonarray.get(i).toString(), Meeting.class);
                            Log.e("Meeting", m.getMeetingId() + " " + m.getStatus());
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    ;
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    txtError(error);
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("Content-Type", "application/json;");
            map.put("Authorization", "Bearer <sometoken>");
            return map;
        }
    };

    //request.setPriority(Request.Priority.HIGH);
    helper.add(request);
}
```

Comment: Try making a JsonObjectRequest and then parse the response with GSON just to see if the request class itself is buggy somewhere. Google docs has been known to have some outdated training data lingering.

Comment: is `onErrorResponse` is getting called?.. if yes what is the log

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line at the beginning

```
RequestQueue helper = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
```

Comment: That has to have been done already or the helper.add(getMeetings) call would throw an NPE

Answer (score 0):

Add these line

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

if you don't want to the save response in cache memory then add this

```
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

According to my personal opinion its better if you pass the application context.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question, my helper.add is calling a request queue defined in my app class